Tesseract usage in C#
I'm trying to use a tesseract in project wrote in C#. I have a problem with reading text from a part of an image. I'm trying to find this 4 signs (in example 0000) and number after "e". Additionally, for some examples it is working perfectly but for some others its printing "Empty page!!!". Difference between examples is color of the background. What should I do to minimize probability of error?
image where reading text from image working
[here is not working]
(https://i.sstatic.net/gwYE2oBI.jpg)
Part of code:
public static class Sign
{
    public static void Check()
    {
        string imagePath = "C:/Users/User/Documents/... .bmp";
        Mat imageSign = new Mat(imagePath);

        int h = imageSign.Rows;
        int w = imageSign.Cols;
        int point1 = (int)(0.01 * w);
        int point2 = (int)(0.6 * h);
        int point3 = (int)(0.3 * w);
        int point4 = (int)(0.9 * h);
        OpenCvSharp.Point start_point = new OpenCvSharp.Point(point1, point2);
        OpenCvSharp.Point end_point = new OpenCvSharp.Point(point3, point4);
        imageSign = new Mat(imageSign, new OpenCvSharp.Rect(point1, point2, point3 - point1, point4 - point2));

        imageSign.SaveImage(imagePath);
        var pixFromFilee = Pix.LoadFromFile(imagePath);
        string customConfig = "--psm 13";
        using (var engined = new TesseractEngine(@"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.Default))
        {
            engined.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");
            using (var pagee = engined.Process(pixFromFilee, customConfig))
            {
                string text = page.GetText();
                Console.Write(text);

                string[] lines = text.Split('\n');
                bool linijka = false;

                foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    if (line.Length == 4 || line.Length == 5)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(" e5: ");
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                        linijka = true;
                    }
                    if (line.Length == 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("e_:");
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }

                if (!linijka)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("not found e5");
                }
                Cv2.ImShow("final", imageSign);
                Cv2.WaitKey(0);
            }
        }

I tried cropping and image and for some reason making it bigger or smaller than it is now, adversely affects on results. Additionally I tried some other tesseract psm configurations.
